# creates temporary which is freed while still in use when reading path of DirEntry

Tags: rust, path, filesystems

I'm trying to read all files in a folder, as simple as that. And then filter for mp4 extensions. But I get following error:

[image: create a temporary which is freed error]

I don't understand, how in the following code, the `e.path` statement could "create a temporary". (The whole code is obviously in them same "Ok" closure.). Is there some special stuff happening in the path() method? I could not find anything strange in the documentation.

```
let paths = fs::read_dir(&folder).unwrap();

for path in paths {
    match path {
        Ok(e) => {
            let fullPath = e.path();
            let extension = e
                .path()
                .extension()
                .expect("Error getting extension")
                .to_str()
                .expect("Could not convert extensions to string");
            println!("{}", extension)
        }

        _ => {}
    }
```

I tried numerous things and stuff like `.path().metadata()` does not throw this error. Only when in combination with `extension()` this seems to be happening? It's really confusing me, how a task this simple becomes so complex.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. I tried to reproduce [with a similar code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b0684924830da599c4de526b007d360), but the error does not appear.

Comment: @justinas it's sadly hard to do so, the function is called in a tauri app with a solidjs frontend. I have no idea how to set up an example of this online...

Comment: Nevermind, I'm in the wrong here, the error does occur when using your example, just wrapped in a `fn main()`. I minimized the example too much, yours is perfect :)

Comment: ok, well then let's hope somebody gets why this is happening :)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of errors/code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DirEntry::path()` returns a `PathBuf`, and `PathBuf::extension()` returns an `Option<&OsStr>`. As you can see, the `OsStr` is borrowed from the original `PathBuf` / `Path`. The problem is, you're trying to bind the extension to a variable, but you do not assign the `PathBuf` that is borrowed from to a variable as well.

So the compiler is correct in saying that the `PathBuf` is temporary, and will be dropped after your `let extension = ...` statement, and thus `extension` can not keep pointing to it.

You're already doing the right thing - assigning another copy of that `PathBuf` to `fullPath`. So you can just borrow the extension from it.

Here's a fully self-contained solution:

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let folder = "./src";
    let paths = fs::read_dir(&folder).unwrap();

    for path in paths {
        if let Ok(e) = path {
            let full_path = e.path(); // This will live at least as long as `extension`, so
                                      // borrowing from it is fine.
            let extension = full_path
                .extension()
                .expect("Error getting extension")
                .to_str()
                .expect("Could not convert extensions to string");
            println!("{}", extension)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, I see now. I though that rust will track "linked references" to it's end, and not drop them after the first one! I just learned something. So I always need to check that an `&anything` method has it's direct ancestor still explicitly in scope (and not "implicitly over linked references..)